# Minecraft 14w20b - How to use execute to teleport?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am using snapshot 14w20b, and I have a problem. I have the following in a command block on a command block `setblock` clock:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=Pig,r=10] ~ ~ ~
```

I expected this to teleport all pigs within a 10 block radius of a snowball to teleport to it, if one exists. However, all pigs remained in place, and further inspection revealed *they were teleporting to themselves*. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT: My goal is to teleport all pigs within range of a snowball to the snowball. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Basically your command says "from the location of all snowballs, teleport all pigs everywhere a relative distance of 0".  The location of the `execute` just determines where the command originates so you do stuff like limit the radius.

Comment: Edited, please read. How can I teleport all pigs within a 10 block radius of a snowball to the snowball?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you didn't tell the pigs who to teleport to. ~ ~ ~ is the location of the selected character, so the pigs are teleporting to themselves.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. I assumed ~ ~ ~ would mean _relative to the entity running the command_ but apparently it isn't.

Comment: This command just works as you intend it to in 1.13 (after converting the `/execute` and the selector to the new syntax: `/execute positioned as @e[type=snowball] run tp @e[type=pig,distance=..10] ~ ~ ~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`/execute @e[type=Pig] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=Pig,c=1] @e[type=Snowball,r=10]`

I haven't quite tested it, but I have done something like that before.
Good luck! :)

Oh, and by the way, the snowball will hit the pig as soon as the pig is teleported.

Comment: Hey this isn't a bad idea. Are you sure @e[type=Pig,c=1] will select the caller though? Isn't the list @e[type=Pig] ordered by UUID or just randomly?

Comment: I ended up changing Pig to WitherSkull (Pig was just so I knew it worked; WitherSkulls don't have hitboxes so the snowball keeps going) with the command `/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=WitherSkull,r=10] @e[type=Snowball,r=1,c=1]` but I'll accept your answer anyway because it helped me come up with the final configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for reference, by experimentation I discovered `r=3` is the minimum required to keep the WitherSkull with the snowball

Comment: Use `@s` instead of `@e[type=Pig,c=1]`